# spatie / laravel-sitemap : How to set homepage priority

Tags: laravel, sitemap

How do you set the priority for a homepage ?

I tried many things, including :

```
SitemapGenerator::create('https://www.example.com')
        ->hasCrawled(function (Url $url) {
            if ($url->segment(1) === 'https://www.example.com') {
                $url->setPriority(1)
                    ->setLastModificationDate(Carbon::create('2016', '1', '1'));
            }

            return $url;
        })
        ->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better still :

```
//We set the homepage priority to 1
            ->hasCrawled(function (Url $url) {
                if (is_null($url->segment(1))) {
                    $url->setPriority(1);
                }
                return $url;
            })
            //We save the file and redirect to it
            ->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
        return redirect(url('sitemap.xml'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find to answer :

```
//We set the homepage priority to 1
            ->hasCrawled(function (Url $url) {
                if ($url->segment(1) === env('https://www.example.com')) {
                    $url->setPriority(1);
                }
                return $url;
            })
            //We save the file and redirect to it
            ->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
        return redirect(url('sitemap.xml'));
```